# How to run javascript tests in intellij using selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, intellij-idea

I have tests in .js which runs remotely using selenium webdriver. But, it gets hard to debug issues locally. I am using IntelliJ IDE and would like to integrate with selenium webdriver and run them using IDE.

Jest is the framework which we use.

Can someone please help me figure this out?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you check the internet for existing tutorials, like https://www.guru99.com/intellij-selenium-webdriver.html , https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/getting-started-with-webdriver-in-java-using-intellij-on-osx , http://seleniumsimplified.com/get-started ?

Comment: All the above are for Java based tests.  Many folks have Javascript based selenium webdriver tests.